# Pandas: how to add column representing the intersection of 2 attributes in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

lets say i have 2 csv files (very large files),

- the first file represents restaurants and have 6 attributes `restaurant_id`, `name`,`star_rating`,`city`,`zone`,`closed`

[image]

- the second file represents the categories of the restaurants and have 2 attributes `restaurant_id` and `category`
  [image]

**So, what i want to do is basically add a column called `zone_categories_intersection` to my features that tells me the number of restaurants in the same area (zone) that share at least one category with the restaurant in question.**

Since it's the first time i use the pandas librairy, i have a little trouble getting fluent when manipulating tables. I did something like this to figure out the number of restaurants in the area associated with the restaurant in question and add it to my features column.

```py
restaurants['nb_restaurants_zone'] = restaurants.groupby('zone')['zone'].transform('size')
restaurants.head()

features = restaurants[['restaurant_id', 'moyenne_etoiles', 'ville', 'zone', 'ferme', 'nb_restaurants_zone']].copy()
features.head()

#edit
merged = restaurants.merge(categories, on='restaurant_id')
merged.head()
```

[image]

**I thought about adding the `category.csv` file and merge it with restaurant and map the categorys with the corresponding id's and then figure out a way to apply the second condition (that share at least one category with the restaurant in question)... but i dont really know how to do any of those things**

Thank you

Comment: @RichieV what i want to do is basically add a column to my features that tells me the number of restaurants in the same area (zone) that share at least one category of food with the restaurant in question. I dont know how to create a table in here to show. you but it's pretty simple.

Comment: @RichieV ohh those tables you see are just the Heads, they are much larger ^^

Comment: and please, always show the tables in a code block, leave the images for things that cannot be shared with text as charts and such

Comment: @RichieV yes nb_restaurants_zone is already showing how many restaurants are in the same zone, but i want to know he number of restaurants in the same area (zone) that share at least one category of food with the restaurant in question.

Comment: I see, please change the images for code blocks including `df.head()` and `df2[df2['restaurant_id'].isin(df.head()['restaurant_id'])]`

Comment: @RichieV i dont know how to add tables in those code blocks

Comment: copy-paste the table, select the pasted text, ctrl+k (or select "Code sample" from the mini-toolbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
# sample data
# (it's not exactly your provided data
# but it is better to show how the code works)
# please always provide a callable line of code
# you could get it with `df.head().to_dict('split')`
rest = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'name': ['Denny\'s', 'Ike\'s Love & Sandwiches', 'Midori Japanese',
        'Pho U', 'John & Sons Oysters'],
    'avg_stars': [2.5, 4, 3.5, 3.5, 4],
    'city': ['Las Vegas', 'Phoenix', 'Calgary', 'Toronto', 'Toronto'],
    'zone': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
})
cats = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, ['Breakfast', 'Dinners', 'American']],
    [2, ['Sandwiches', 'American']],
    [3, ['Japanese']],
    [4, ['Japanese']],
    [5, ['American', 'Seafood']]
], columns=['id', 'category']).explode('category')
```

The code

```
# add zone to categories dataframe
cats2 = cats.merge(rest[['id', 'zone']], on='id')

# add count for zone & category
cats2['zone_cat_count'] = (
    cats2.groupby(['zone', 'category'])
    .transform('count')
)

# merge with rest dataframe
rest = rest.merge(
    cats2.groupby('id')['zone_cat_count'].max()
    , on='id'
)
```

Output

```
   id                     name  avg_stars       city zone  zone_cat_count
0   1                  Denny's        2.5  Las Vegas    a               3
1   2  Ike's Love & Sandwiches        4.0    Phoenix    a               3
2   3          Midori Japanese        3.5    Calgary    b               2
3   4                    Pho U        3.5    Toronto    b               2
4   5      John & Sons Oysters        4.0    Toronto    a               3
```

Comment: Thanks you i tried the steps with my tables and it seems to work. Is it fine as well if i had added the categories to the rest dataframe (not added zone to categories like you did) and did the count there with .groupby('id')['zone_cat_count'].max(), on='id' ? Also, why did you use .max?

Comment: For displaying tables correctly in here, so i just use `df.head().to_dict('split')` on what i want to share and copy the text directly on a code block here?

Comment: that would give the first five rows from the dataframe, see [how to provide a relevant sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)... maybe the first 5 rows don't show the complexity of your data, in that case include more rows with `df.head(20)` or create a new toy dataframe

Comment: for example the first 5 rows of the categories dataframe would not be enough for this sample, you would need all the relevant `restaurant_id`

Comment: Is it fine as well if i had added the categories to the rest dataframe (not added zone to categories like you did) and did the count there with .groupby('id')['zone_cat_count'].max(), on='id' ? and, why did you use .max?

Comment: when you group `cats2` by `id` you need an aggregation column, and in this case you are looking for the maximum number of shared categories... as for the zone stuff, if it is not what you need then I just don't understand your question, hope you can solve your problem with what I've provided, best of luck